# not able to get aacp stream

Tags: android, aac

I am trying to play an live AACP stream in android. For this I used AACP decoder and I think its working fine because I have tested with many AACP streams and working great.
But my stream is which I am unable to play. please help me.[enter link description here][1]

http://listen.cheapeststream.com/api/listen/?mount=SAM03AAC265&method=sc

Answer (score 1):

Found this library, hope it works for you.

https://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/